# How can I make node.js logging format closing parens to match opening parens?

Tags: node.js, logging, formatting, parentheses

Recent versions of node `console.log(object)` return:

```
{ top: 
  { child: 
    { anotherChild: 'someValue' } } }
```

How do I make it return a more traditional:

```
{ 
  top: { 
    child: { 
      anotherChild: 'someValue'  
    } 
  } 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try something like `util.inspect`? https://nodejs.org/api/util.html

Answer (score 0):

It's possible I misunderstood the question ... is there a reason you can't use `JSON.strinfigy` to format the object and then `console.log` it? `JSON.stringify` accepts additional parameters that control the level of indentation.

```
> a = { top: { child: { anotherChild: 'someValue' } } }
> console.log(JSON.stringify(a, null, 2))

{
  "top": {
    "child": {
      "anotherChild": "someValue"
    }
  }
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

> JSON.stringify(value[, replacer[, space]])

In particular

> space Optional
>
> A String or Number object that's used to insert white space into the output JSON string for readability purposes. If this is a Number,
> it indicates the number of space characters to use as white space;
> this number is capped at 10 if it's larger than that. Values less than
> 1 indicate that no space should be used. If this is a String, the
> string (or the first 10 characters of the string, if it's longer than
> that) is used as white space. If this parameter is not provided (or is
> null), no white space is used.

Comment: Yes. I'd like to change the behaviour of console log , if possible, rather than have to make an alias that calls console.log.